How to describe not-quite-exact quotations
Many catchy turns of phrase, when originally uttered or printed, are in their original form not as catchy as they could be if edited for stand-alone usage.  As a simple example, someone might say

(Some category of thing) are X.  They (lots of text about that category).  In short, they (does something, phrased in catchy way).

If popular usage morphs that into "(Some category of thing) (does something, phrased in catchy way)", how should one describe the latter sentence.  The sentence as a whole isn't an exact quotation, but nor is it a paraphrase.
On a related note, how should one attribute popular sayings which are misquotations of things famous people said?  A 1971 book entitled "Dangers to Children and Youth: Accidents...poison...prevention" says:

Yogi Berra once commented that "it ain't over until the fat lady sings."  For the human organism, it's all over once the cerebral hemispheres have been deprived of blood supply for long enough to cause irreversible and irrecoverable...

I know of no other printed citation for Yogi Berra saying that.  He did say "It ain't over 'til it's over", and there was a many-decades-old somewhat popular saying "The (religious service) isn't over until the fat lady sings",  I don't think the author of the book was intending to coin a new phraseology for that sentence, and so citing the author of the book as the author of the quotation feels a little weird, but I think that book may be the first time the "fat lady" quote appeared in print with that exact "It ain't" wording.
Finally, what term should be used to describe the use of a turn of phrase which is patterned off a popular one, but with a deliberately different meaning, e.g. what would a romance novelist character be doing if she claimed a right to "life, liberty, and the pursuit of sappiness"?

One thing you didn't ask, but might want: the term for crediting the wrong person is "misattribution."

@AndyBonner: I'm familiar with that term, which would apply if X quoted Y as saying something, when it was actually Z that said it and Y had said nothing of the sort.  Not sure whether it would apply if Z was borrowing Y's phraseology, or if Y had borrowed Z's phraseology but was in fact the first person to use the exact quoted wording.

According to the Library of Congress book, Respectfully Quoted, the phrase "the opera ain't over till the fat lady sings" was coined in 1978 by Dan Cook, a sports writer from San Antonio, Texas, after his town's basketball team had gone one up in a championship series. No obvious connection to Yogi Berra there.

@FumbleFingers: The book I referred to predates that quote; if memory serves, it was in the late 1960s.

Well, it could be ain't, isn't, or is not over..., so I just searched Google Books for over till the fat lady sings. Which found nothing before those 2 in 1977. It would be very odd if your source predated them.

@FumbleFingers: The book is Dangers to Children and Youth: Accidents...poison...prevention dated 1971: 'Yogi Berra once commented that " it ain't over until the fat lady sings . " For the human organism , it's all over once the cerebral hemispheres have been deprived of blood supply for long enough to cause irreversible and irrecoverable'

So I guess I misremembered "until" versus "'til", but still the phraseology with "It ain't over" rather than "The [whatever] isn't over" exists here in 1971--well before the 1978 basketball quote.  In any case, my main interest was how to distinguish "paraphrasing", which is often associated with to avoid the use of any clever turns of phrase in the original, versus adjusting a sentence in such a way as to retain them.

Well, it's certainly at least "odd", given that Dangers to Children and Youth:... is in the Google Books indexes, but my searches didn't find your text (I did actually check all three of "over till / until / til the fat lady sings", but only the first one found anything remotely relevant). It looks like all the websites (and The Guardian newspaper of 1978, reporting president Carter's then-recent use of it) ascribing the origin to sports writer Dan Cook are simply mistaken.

@FumbleFingers: Returning to my original point, I was wondering if there's any concise way of distinguishing the different things one might do with a quote, which might avoid borrowing the wording while keeping the original meaning, or borrow the wording while changing the meaning.  Both might be "paraphrasing", but if so that word seems so ambiguous to fairly describe what should be very different concepts.  Perhaps referring to e.g. "what might be called, with appologies to Thomas Jefferson, the right to life, liberty, and the pursuit of sappiness" is the best way to deal with such usages.

Well, apart from your good self, how many people need to identify a whole class of trivial deviations from some precise "original" text? After all, lots of writers revise their own words, and we have multiple versions / translations of Shakespeare and the Bible (which between the two of them probably account for half of all "frequently [mis]quoted" references in English. But I certainly think ...with apologies to [[mis]quoted author would be the best approach in most contexts.

Many people forget that 'paraphrase' is a noun as well as a verb. We mainly use it as a verb, saying something has been paraphrased, for example. But Oxford defines the noun as 'a rewording of something written or spoken'. That sounds exactly what you are describing.
So, if you use a phrase or saying that is very close to a famous quotation, that part of your speech is "a paraphrase". If the popular phrase is very close to the original then you could perhaps call it a close paraphrase or even an approximate quotation.
Of course, any quotation or paraphrased quotation by definition acknowledges the original speaker. If you aren't aware someone else said it then you aren't quoting them and it isn't a quote. As you explained, some quotations become so popular they would be better described as an idiom or a saying.
In written English, style guides tend to cover the treatment of quotations. Quotations are contained in quotation marks. Paraphrased quotes are not, but you would expect the original source to be acknowledged. You could take this as a principle for spoken word, too. Would you put it in quote marks if written? Then it's a quotation. Would you paraphrase it, but acknowledge the source? Then it's a paraphrase. Or is it just a saying like "it ain't over 'til it's over" which countless people must say without even wondering where it came from? Then it is just a popular phrase or idiom.
If you wanted to talk about the phenomenon of people paraphrasing famous quotations without being aware of their origin, then I suppose you could refer to them as popular paraphrases. I don't think 'misquotations' is the right term at all, because that implies that someone is trying to quote but unintentionally getting it wrong.

I've usually seen the term "paraphrase" used in a manner that implies an intention to phrase something in an entirely original fashion, rather than using a mix of orgiinal and revised content.

@supercat there are so many possibilities here, I don't think there is a single answer. But I've added a bit to mine to try and cover some more possibilities.

@supercat Looking at the MW entry for "paraphrase", I find a usage example that is very close to the sort of thing you're talking about, in which a quotation of someone else has been slightly intentionally altered, but the structure left intact:

"The Left’s answer to the focus on President Biden’s debilitated state is — to paraphrase the old gibe about Rudy Giuliani’s tendency to bring everyone back to September 11 — a noun, a verb, an overheated adjective, and Project 2025." Apparently the original quote about Giuliani was "There's only three things he mentioned in his sentence, a noun, a verb, and 9/11."

@AndyBonner: The way I'd been taught the term "paraphrase" in school, paraphrasing the old gibe would be something like "His sentence mentioned nothing except the subject, the action, and the September 11 terrorist attacks", keeping the same meaning as the original sentence.  Perhaps the word as a accommodates usage, but that would still leave the question about how to distinguish what I did with the sentence I gave above from what was done to sentence involving Project 25.

@supercat Meh, words can have multiple meanings and not every concept has a single word. The rest of the MW page makes it clear that your use is also appropriate. If we want to distinguish a "loose/broad paraphrase" from something closer, we can simply explain our meaning in extra words: "Lowry adapted the quote about Giuliani to his purposes," etc.

"Misquote" is quite general, it can mean getting some of the words wrong, or omitting some of the words, or it can be used for a "misattribution". It often has the implication that the change is significant because it changes the meaning of what the original person said.

"Play it again, Sam" as Bogart is often misquoted.


"In the future all learning will be online" - Steve Jobs

"Paraphrase" saying the same meaning with different words, while preserving the meaning.  This could include omitting words.

To paraphrase Steve Jobs, computers continue to revolutionise education.

"Quote" with ellipsis.  If you are just removing words, you can call it a quote.  But to be honest, you should mark the omission with an ellipsis

"Computers ... will revolutionise the way we learn" - Steve Jobs.

Generally we don't use a special word for what you describe.  It's a type of "quote"  But depending it could be a misquote or a paraphrase
